# SSL/TLSV1 connection using C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ssl, starttls

I am trying to establish `SSL/TLS` connection to my personal chat server.
My code snippet  is as follows

```
public void StartAuthentication(XMPPConnection connection) 
    {
        NetworkStream networkStream = new NetworkStream(connection._sock);
        _sslStream = new SslStream(networkStream, false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate), new LocalCertificateSelectionCallback(ClientCertificateSelectionCallback));
        X509CertificateCollection collection = new X509CertificateCollection();
        collection.Add(new X509Certificate(@"D:\ca-certs\AddTrust_External_Root.pem"));
        collection.Add(new X509Certificate(@"D:\ca-certs\America_Online_Root_Certification_Authority_1.pem"));
        collection.Add(new X509Certificate(@"D:\ca-certs\AOL_Member_CA.pem"));
        collection.Add(new X509Certificate(@"D:\ca-certs\Baltimore_CyberTrust_Root.pem"));
        collection.Add(new X509Certificate(@"D:\ca-certs\CAcert_Class3.pem"));
        collection.Add(new X509Certificate(@"D:\ca-certs\CAcert_Root.pem"));
        collection.Add(new X509Certificate(@"D:\ca-certs\Deutsche_Telekom_Root_CA_2.pem"));
        collection.Add(new X509Certificate(@"D:\ca-certs\DigiCertHighAssuranceCA-3.pem"));
        collection.Add(new X509Certificate(@"D:\ca-certs\DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.pem"));
        collection.Add(new X509Certificate(@"D:\ca-certs\Entrust.net_2048.pem"));
        collection.Add(new X509Certificate(@"D:\ca-certs\Entrust.net_Secure_Server_CA.pem"));
        collection.Add(new X509Certificate(@"D:\ca-certs\Equifax_Secure_CA.pem"));
        collection.Add(new X509Certificate(@"D:\ca-certs\Equifax_Secure_Global_eBusiness_CA-1.pem"));
        collection.Add(new X509Certificate(@"D:\ca-certs\Go_Daddy_Class_2_CA.pem"));
        collection.Add(new X509Certificate(@"D:\ca-certs\GTE_CyberTrust_Global_Root.pem"));
        collection.Add(new X509Certificate(@"D:\ca-certs\Microsoft_Internet_Authority_2010.pem"));
        collection.Add(new X509Certificate(@"D:\ca-certs\Microsoft_Secure_Server_Authority_2010.pem"));
        collection.Add(new X509Certificate(@"D:\ca-certs\StartCom_Certification_Authority.pem"));
        collection.Add(new X509Certificate(@"D:\ca-certs\Thawte_Premium_Server_CA.pem"));
        collection.Add(new X509Certificate(@"D:\ca-certs\Thawte_Primary_Root_CA.pem"));
        collection.Add(new X509Certificate(@"D:\ca-certs\ValiCert_Class_2_VA.pem"));
        collection.Add(new X509Certificate(@"D:\ca-certs\VeriSign_Class_3_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G2.pem"));
        collection.Add(new X509Certificate(@"D:\ca-certs\VeriSign_Class_3_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G5.pem"));
        collection.Add(new X509Certificate(@"D:\ca-certs\VeriSign_Class_3_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G5_2.pem"));
        collection.Add(new X509Certificate(@"D:\ca-certs\VeriSign_Class3_Extended_Validation_CA.pem"));
        collection.Add(new X509Certificate(@"D:\ca-certs\Verisign_Class3_Primary_CA.pem"));
        collection.Add(new X509Certificate(@"D:\ca-certs\VeriSign_International_Server_Class_3_CA.pem"));
        try 
        {
            _sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient("lap-020.alumnus.co.in", collection, SslProtocols.Tls, true);

        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Now after execution of the program

> `_sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient("lap-020.alumnus.co.in", collection,
>   SslProtocols.Tls, true);`

The main thread block. Probably for this the ssl handshake not start. Now tell me why the main thread block. Thanks

Comment: I am using **openfire** server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much C#, but from the documentation of AuthenticateAsClient it expects here client certificates you use to authenticate yourself against the SSL server. And these must have a private key, otherwise you cannot use them. But, what you use as certificates are the trusted root certificates, which get used to check the certificate of the server and where you don't have a private key for.

Maybe you need to make yourself more familiar with the basics of SSL, e.g. who uses which certificates and why etc.

Answer (score -1):

```
X509Certificate2Collection certificates = new X509Certificate2Collection();
certificates.Import(**uri**, **CertPass**, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (a, b, c, d) => true;
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(host);
req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
req.ClientCertificates = certificates;
req.Method = "GET";
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
var html = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```